# How do I access the /bugreports directory from an Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, bug-reporting

With adb, I am able to see that the /bugreports directory is not empty on my Android device.
`adb shell ls /bugreports/*`

I wrote some Kotlin code to access the /bugreports directory on my Android device. The following code does not find any files.

```
File("bugreports").walk().forEach {
    Log.i(tag, "Debug: " + it)
}
```

I have tried including android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in my manifest file. I have tried using runtime permissions and special permissions as described in the Android documentation. Is there some other way to access the /bugreports directory from an Android app?

Comment: The adb shell has more permissions that an app that is jailed in it's sandbox.